Configuring CMS Connect Header Source to point to Visualforce Page being blocked?
What I configured :
I created a VF page that calls a custom tag e.g.  that displays the header UI perfectly when I press the preview button. Also in the VF settings I made sure to :

Tick the "Available for Lightning Experience, Experience Builder sites, and the mobile app"
Untick the "Require CSRF protection on GET requests" (Help page mentioned "If you want to use the page in an Experience Builder template, make sure that Require CSRF protection on GET requests isn’t selected, because it prevents the page from rendering")

So I've configured my CMS Connection as according to this page where in the Server URL, I inputted in the domain https://<mysandboxdomain>--<sandboxname>--c.sandbox.vf.force.com.
Finally, navigating to Experience Cloud Builder > Settings > CMS Connect where I choose the Header Source (CMS Connection I created in previous step) and the "Header Path" to apex/<VF Page I created previously>.
Testing phase
When the Experience Cloud Builder is reloaded, I get this error below (see screenshot) :

Upon inspecting further via the Google Dev Console I get this error message :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at
'https://----c.sandbox.vf.force.com/apex/'
from origin
'https://--.sandbox.live-preview.salesforce-experience.com'
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource.

I made sure to add all the URLs into Trusted URLs and the CORS and still this error. Is there some platform limitation in this?
